# Debugging the C++ Standard Library functions in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017

I've noticed that in VS 2010 Professional(in university) you can step into stl and stdlib functions and debug the actual insides, tried to do the same in VS 2017 Community but it didn't work, it even refuses to disassemble them, same goes for VS 2013 Ultimate(i assumed it's a professional version feature).

Now i'm wondering if there is a way to make this work in 2017 community or 2013 ultimate, am i doing anything wrong? I know you can probably find all the source codes on the internet, but i want to make it work in visual studio, so that i can actually debug it.

Comment: Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols.  Turn on the symbol server at least once so you get the .PDB file for the runtime library.  For VS2017 also use Tools > Options > Debugging > General, "Enable Just My Code" unticked.

Comment: forgot to mention that i tried unticking "Enable just my code" in vs 2013 ultimate and didn't do anything, but everything worked in both 2013 and 2017 after i enabled the symbol server, so thanks a lot